# Imagick jpeg:size option not working on one server but not the other

Tags: centos, php, imagemagick

Not sure if this should be posted here or on stackoverflow so figured this was the safer bet. I'm using Imagick to resize jpegs. This is part of the code

```
$prehintSize = (int) $requestedWidth > $requestedHeight ? $requestedWidth : $requestedHeight;
$imgckObj = new Imagick();
$imgckObj->setOption('jpeg:size', $prehintSize . 'x' . $prehintSize);
$imgckObj->readImage($sourceFilePath);
```

Basically `$imgckObj->setOption('jpeg:size', $prehintSize . 'x' . $prehintSize);` is used to give a hint to libjpeg how much of the file needs to be loaded into RAM resulting in close to a 10x performance boost. This works great on my servers running Ubuntu with PHP running under Apache. On my other server running CentOS with PHP running through suPHP while the code still works it's obviously getting ignored since it's not getting sped up at all. I'm wondering if this is a limitation that I can't get around due to suPHP or if I just need to config something else.

I would think it would of already had it but in case this could be part of the issue, I'm running ImageMagick 6.5.4-7 on centos as that's the latest that yum will pull. For Ubuntu I'm running ImageMagick 6.6.9-7 Thanks for your help.

Comment: Looks like the version of Imagemagick is the issue. Looking at the change log http://www.imagemagick.org/script/changelog.php

6.5.6-2 added the required parameter.

I update Imagemagick by compiling from source using the following directions:
http://equella.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/10272

It did install into /usr/bin/local so you might need to create a symlink to /usr/bin to get it working.

Comment: Well done for finding a solution! Could you post it as an answer and accept it?

Comment: Yeah, it wouldn't let me as not enough time had passed. Will do so now.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the version of Imagemagick is the issue. Looking at the change log imagemagick.org/script/changelog.php 6.5.6-2 added the required parameter.

I updated Imagemagick by compiling from source using the following directions: http://equella.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/10272
It did install into /usr/bin/local so you might need to create a symlink to /usr/bin to get it working. Now I got my performance boost again :)